# New at kubernetes, how do I expose my pod to external traffic?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I am new at kubernetes and I have a cluster with docker desktop with a pod which has my back end in a container and so far I know that a service attaches to a pod (pods) and provides a static IP which allows for external traffic (I want to hit my backend with my browser). I am unsure how to do this and nothing online really makes sense.

I think I need to make my service a load balancer type to allow a static IP to pass traffic into my pods (I have only one but I will up the replicas when this works).

I can't seem to get it to work, here are the config files that are relevant:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: my-app
  name: my-app
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-app
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: my-app
        image: my-app/my-app
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        env:
        - name: GET_HOSTS_FROM
          value: dns
        - name: DATABASE_URL
          value: postgres://postgres:postgres@database/postgres
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80

--------------------------------------------

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-app
  labels:
    app: my-app
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 8080 
  selector:
    app: my-app
```

I ultimately want to put this on aws or gcp but I am a bit lost on where to go from here, if anyone has any advice or material that can help a brainlet like me understand this I would **really** appreciate it.

EDIT: I have added an ingress here and I am not too sure what should be happening when hooked up to the service:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-srv
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
    - host: lesser-bank.com
      http:
        paths:
          - pathType: Prefix
            path: "/test"
            backend:
              service:
                name: lesser-bank-api
                port:
                  number: 8080
```

Answer (score 0):

Services are of type `ClusterIp` by default which means that your pods can only be accessed from within the cluster.

An object of kind [Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) can provide external access to your service, something like this:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-srv
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
spec:
  rules:
    - host: acme.com
      http:
        paths:
          - pathType: Prefix
            path: "/myapp"
            backend:
              service:
                name: my-app
                port:
                  number: 80
```

This is a very common question and can be found easily in the Kubernetes docs.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, have edited my post to add an ingress, if the ingress looks for the service should it be reachable on my machine when I go to acme.com/myapp?

Comment: in the `ingress` object, the service name should match your `service` object name which is `my-app`. The `host` is optional and should point to your localhost (when testing locally) then `acme.com/myapp` would be the address of your service

Answer (score 0):

If you want to expose just one deployment then it will be ideal to just expose your service via a Loadbalancer type. Refer to this [link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/create-external-load-balancer/) for detailed explanation.

However, if you want to use Nginx Ingress controller with Let's Encrypt and Cert Manager, please refer to the following link for a detailed explanation and instructions:

https://github.com/digitalocean/Kubernetes-Starter-Kit-Developers/blob/main/03-setup-ingress-controller/nginx.md

```yaml
---

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: my-app
  name: my-app
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-app
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: my-app
        image: my-app/my-app
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        env:
        - name: GET_HOSTS_FROM
          value: dns
        - name: DATABASE_URL
          value: postgres://postgres:postgres@database/postgres
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-app
  labels:
    app: my-app
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer #add this line to expose your deployment
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 8080 
  selector:
    app: my-app
```